# Get the differences between updated value and the original record

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using Symfony2 framework. Is there any easy way to get the different values between updated record and the original record?

Answer (score 2):

1. You can create a tempo variable who is a copy from your original
   entity converted in array.
2. You update your original entity
3. You create a new tempo2 variable who is a copy from your entity
   updated, converted in array.
4. You use 'array_diff' php function to get change.

---

```
$tempo = (array) $entity;
$entity update code;
$tempo2 = (array) $entity;
$changes = array_diff(tempo, tempo2);
```

In your repo, you can use 
$query->getArrayResult(); 
to get the entity in array form;

---

I know it's not a quickly method, it's just what i use. I don't know other way to get changes....